# Dictionary comprehension to apply a function to DataFrame columns

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

The goal of my code is to use dictionary comprehension to apply a function, called stdev_of_list, to a data frame, called final, for every column that has a numeric (float or int) data type.

```
{i:stdev_of_list(final[i] for i in final.columns if (final[i].dtype==float) or (final[i].dtype==int))}
```

I am getting a syntax error, and am not sure what is causing it, please let me know what else I need to provide to help understand the situation!

Comment: `{col.name:stdev_of_list(col) for col in [final[i] for i in final.columns if (final[i].dtype=='float64') or (final[i].dtype=='int64')]}` Try this

Comment: Just a misplaced paren: {i:stdev_of_list(final[i] **)** ...

Answer (score 0):

```
{col.name:stdev_of_list(col) for col in [final[i] for i in final.columns if (final[i].dtype=='float64') or (final[i].dtype=='int64')]}
```

This should do it.